# MonoDevelop: Changing Symbol Usage Highlighting color

Tags: monodevelop, highlighting

Symbol Usage Highlighting was added to MonoDevelop in version 2.4 and is described as follows:

> When placing the cursor over a symbol, MonoDevelop will now
>   automatically highlight all usages of that symbol in the editor. The
>   keys control+shift+up/down can be user to jump between symbol
>   instances.

I can't seem to find how to change the colors associated with this new feature (I assumed that Options\Syntax Highlighting would hold the colors like it does for everything else, but I don't see the entry that's associated with S.U.H.).

I can't download a newer version of MonoDevelop as I'm using it with Unity and doing so will cause issues with the debugger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Preferences > Syntax Highlighting
2. Create a new scheme. Edit it
3. Modify the foreground color of "Bracket marker"

Its not nice that the bracket highlight color is the same as variables, but it works.

I'm using version 2.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Symbol usage highlighting seems to use the bracket marker's foreground color. It's the color argument in the entry:

```
<Style name="marker.bracket" color="#CB4915" bgColor="#67322C" />
```

At least when using MonoDevelop 3.0.1 it is.